# Returning a reference to a structure from a function

Tags: c++, function, reference, structure

Hi I was reading about reference variables in c++ and was reading about reference to a structure and returning a reference to a structure from a function. The example code i read is below :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct sysop {
  char name[26];
  char quote[64];
  int used;
};

const sysop & use(sysop & sysopref);

int main()
{
  sysop looper = {"Rick Looper", "I'm a goto kind of guy.", 0};
  use (looper);
  cout << “Looper: “ << looper.used << “ use(s)\n”;
  sysop copycat;
  copycat = use(looper);
  cout << “Looper: “ << looper.used << “ use(s)\n”;
  cout << “Copycat: “ << copycat.used << “ use(s)\n”;
  cout << “use(looper): “ << use(looper).used << “ use(s)\n”;
  return 0;
}

const sysop & use(sysop & sysopref)
{
  cout << sysopref.name << “ says:\n”;
  cout << sysopref.quote << endl;
  sysopref.used++;
  return sysopref;
}
```

This is from C++ Primer Plus book. Anyways i understood the example but the statement that confused me is `use(looper)`. I mean the function prototype says to return a reference to a constant structure variable, but in this statement, the function is not returning any reference. I am not sure if there is special thing about reference to constant structures or something that allows the function to be used without returning the data or what.

Can someone please explain me this??

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you told us what you thought it _would_ look like otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> but in this statement, the function is not returning any reference.

That is incorrect. The function still returns a `const` reference. The return value is being ignored at the point of the call.

You could use:

```
sysop const& ref = use (looper);
```

to capture the return value of the function.

Comment: Agree, the function is still returning a const reference. My question is, isn't it syntactically incorrect or is it allowed in certain special cases to not have any reference variable to capture the return type??

Comment: @PuneetMittal: What do you mean? The reference variable is right there, in the function's argument list. You could return a reference to a global if you liked.

Comment: @PuneetMittal, the return values of functions can be ignored regardless of the return type.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks. I just tried couple of other examples and found that yes "the return values of a function can be ignored regardless of return type." Never saw such code before so I was surprised if this was syntactically correct or not. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Answer (score 0):

> the statement that confused me is use(looper). I mean the function prototype says to return a reference to a constant structure variable, but in this statement, the function is not returning any reference.

Yes, it does. You have to read the *whole* statement, particularly where it says the return type is `sysop const&`. That's a reference type.

In this case you pass a reference into the function and pass the same reference straight back out.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean the function prototype says to return a reference to a constant
>   structure variable, but in this statement, the function is not
>   returning any reference.

`sysopref` is already a reference when you accept it as a parameter in use `use(sysop & sysopref)`. You simply chanel it when you return the variable from your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sysop & use(sysop & sysopref)
```

`use` accepts non-const reference to instance of type `sysop` - that means, that when we call `use` this way:

```
sysop s;
use(s);
```

`use` works on `s` directly, not its copy (this is how references work). That is required, because `use` modifies its parameter:

```
sysopref.used++;
```

However, it returns its parameter as const reference (probably to avoid further modifications or something). It doesn't matter, that parameter is non-const reference - it is "promoted" (but it wouldn't work the other way around).

So, after this sequence of calls:

```
sysop s;
const sysop& ret_ref = use(s);
```

`ret_ref` will be a reference to `s` (they will share the memory and contain exactly the same data). Look at this sample:

```
int main()
{
    sysop s;
    s.used = 0;

    const sysop& ret_ref = use(s);

    std::cout<<s.used<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<ret_ref.used<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<&(s)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<&(ret_ref)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1

0xbfc910f0
0xbfc910f0
```

As you can see, their memory addresses are exactly the same, so function indeed returned passed parameter.

Try this code [here](http://ideone.com/QiNJ1o).